# Is Double room the same as master bedroom?

Tags: word-usage

I am translating a touristic text and I have encountered this difficulty. In Spanish, we say "habitación de matrimonio", which means something like "the room of the couple of the house, the room for the parents". I have found too that in English you use "double room" and "master bedroom", and I would like to know if they can be used interchangeably or if they have different meanings. Thanks in advance, and please excuse my English, I am not a native speaker.

Comment: Never heard of a double room. I’d assume it was two rooms joined together in some way.

Comment: In (UK?) English there is both "master bedroom" and "double bedroom". A double bedroom is one that is big enough for a double bed (called a *matrimoniale* in Italian, and I assume something similar in Spanish). A single bedroom is one that is only large enough for a single bed. A house can have multiple double bedrooms and single bedrooms. One may be called the master bedroom; this would typically be the largest or "best" (in some sense) double bedroom.

Comment: @JamesRandom - That looks like a pretty comprehensive answer to me; why not post it?

Comment: In the US, in hotels/motels, "double room" generally refers to a room with two beds.  "Master bedroom" generally refers to a bedroom in a normal residence, where it is the largest bedroom, often with connected bathroom, intended for the senior married couple.

Comment: I would say that **habitación de matrimonio** is the equivalent of  **master bedroom** in a private house and possibly **honeymoon suite** in an hotel. In the UK a **double room** is one which contains a _double bed_ (big enough for two adults), a **twin room** is one with two _single beds_ (each big enough for one adult) and a **single room** is one with one single bed. Obviously a "master bedroom" is, usually, a "double room" but it is possible to see houses for sale advertised as having "three double bedrooms".

Comment: In US usage, the "master bedroom" usually also is associated with the "master bath", a bathroom only entered from the bedroom.  This is not referred to as a "double room" even though it entails two rooms; but sometimes is called the "master suite"

Comment: @user662852 A "double room" in the UK isn't two connected rooms, that's either an ensuite room if the second room is a bathroom or shower room or a suite. A "double room" is a room for two people, usually with a double bed in it. This is as opposed to a "single room" which is a room for one person. Do US hotels only have "double" rooms and, if the do have "single" rooms how do they distinguish between them?

Answer (score 1):

These are two different things. A double room is a hotel term.  From [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/double-room)

> a room in a hotel with two beds

While Master Bedroom refers to the largest room in a residence or home, that would usually be the room for the home's owner(s), or the couple.  Again from [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/master-bedroom)

> The master bedroom in a large house is the largest bedroom.